# How to Dual Boot XP and Windows 8 with Windows 8 Consumer Preview Installed First?

Tags: windows, windows-xp, boot

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to dual boot when Windows XP was installed after Windows 7?](https://superuser.com/questions/305764/how-to-dual-boot-when-windows-xp-was-installed-after-windows-7)

As the title suggests, I had a Windows 8 Consumer Preview Installation. I switched back to XP without removing the Windows 8 partition. Now Xp has written its MBR and it's not recognizing Windows 8 Consumer Preview. How to add Windows 8 entery in Boot menu?

Comment: Been asked a thousand times here...http://support.microsoft.com/kb/919529

Answer (score 0):

Quick automatic solution - [Dual-boot Repair](http://boyans.net/DualBootRepair.html) tool.