# How to boot into Windows 7 after installing Windows XP on the same HDD?

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, hard-drive, boot

I installed Windows XP in an unallocated space of a HDD that already had Windows 7 installed on. Installation completed, Windows XP boots, but Windows 7 won't. From the moment I press the power button it boots straight to Windows XP. It shows no OS choice menu, and when I press and hold F8 to get to advanced start options and switch over to the OS choice menu I see only "Windows XP Professional".

How do I boot into Windows 7 now? How do I get a boot menu where I can pick and choose which OS to load? Do I have to do it all over again now?

---

I did a clean install of Windows XP. So I booted from the Windows XP disc, and in the setup program I just chose to install it to the unallocated space on the disk drive. I only had two primary partitions on the HDD. But instead of creating a third primary partition, the setup program created an extended partition and a logical partition inside it. See screenshot below.

[image: a]

That F partition was not there when I started Windows XP installation. It was unallocated space.

> Who said that Windows can only be installed on a primary partition?

---

I have already tried the Dual-boot Repair tool and the Visual BCD Editor without any success. The latter won't even run. Because Windows XP didn't use BCD store.

[image: b]

Comment: When you installed Windows XP, the original MBR was overwritten. That's why you can't boot Windows 7 now.

Comment: You think? What tool do I need to repair it? bootsect.exe? Note that I don't just want to go back to Windows 7. I want to keep Windows XP, and be able to choose which one to load.

Comment: Install Windows XP first, then install Windows 7. - http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/install-multiple-operating-system-multiboot#1TC=windows-7

Comment: Good news! I used the Automatic option of the Dual-boot Repair tool. Now I can boot into Windows 7 again. But I can't boot into Windows XP.

Comment: @joeqwerty Yeah, I figured that out. But it's easier said than done. But now that I can boot into Windows 7 again, can't I just add that Windows XP installation to the OS choice menu?

Comment: No. You have to install the older operating system first, which in this case is Windows XP.

Comment: @joeqwerty That's too much work for one night! :) You're absolutely, positively, sure I can't do it the other way around? I think [HTG](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/8790/dual-boot-your-pre-installed-windows-7-computer-with-xp/) begs to differ.

Comment: Been there and done that now. I tried rewriting the MBR with EasyBCD 2.2 just as explained over at HTG, but to no avail. He did create a new primary partition manually and format it as NTFS. While mine was auto-created by Windows XP setup as a logical partition. That could be the issue. I'm just guessing here. I will try reinstalling Windows XP and following the HTG guide precisely.

Comment: Possible duplicate/related question: [How to dual boot when Windows XP was installed after Windows 7?](http://superuser.com/questions/305764/how-to-dual-boot-when-windows-xp-was-installed-after-windows-7)

Answer (score 3):

**You do not have to reinstall anything** - you have already installed Windows XP after having Windows 7.

A) **You run Dual-boot Repair -> "Automatic Repair" in Windows XP.**

This will make you boot by default to Windows 7.

B) In Windows 7 run Visual BCD Editor.

C) **Type F9 (or context menu "Create missing Windows loaders")** - this will create boot loader/menu entry for Windows XP in Windows 7 BCD (Boot Configuration Data) store. After reboot you will have a dual-boot choice of Windows 7 and Windows XP.

**That's all.** And it's that simple ;)

Comment: Right! Or! Or you install a second HDD, and install XP onto that! Then, you press F12 for boot menu, pick your XP HDD and Voila! Or not so much... Been there, tried that, I got `invalid BOOT.INI` and then `Windows could not start because the following file is missing or corrupt: <Windows root>\system32\ntoskrnl.exe Please re-install a copy of the above file.` So I couldn't complete XP installation on the same HDD that 7 was on (following the HTG guide above) nor could I boot into Windows 7 without hitting that error. Had to put the Windows 7 disc in, and do Start Repair.

Comment: After that, I installed a second HDD to try to install XP onto that one. Same thing as before, Windows setup copies files to the second HDD, then reboots and corrupts everything so that not even Windows 7 will load. Despite the fact that I am installing it on a physically different HDD now...

Comment: Screw this! I will take a break now, then boot and nuke both HDDs tomorrow, and start all over again. Making sure I install XP first, and 7 second. I might try your method first... if I can manage to boot into either one of the systems.

Comment: You might want to point to Microsoft KnowledgeBase article 919529.

Answer (score 0):

Booting is not rocket science.

1. BIOS Firmware boots to first disk set in firmware.
2. MBR from first disk is loaded and executed.
3. Active partition is taken from info in MBR.
4. Boot record of active partition is loaded.

In case Windows XP the file "ntldr" from active partition is loaded and executed, in case Windows 7 the file "bootmgr" (from active partition) is loaded and executed.

Boot configuration data for XP is stored in "boot.ini" or in "\boot\BCD" for Windows 7.

So the main thing - **all boot related files must be on active partition** (for XP and for 7)

Windows boot loader cannot boot a system on another physical disk AFAIK - you have to use BIOS boot selection key for another disk.

When you install any Windows version to a disk you must detach all other disks to avoid future boot problems !!!